# Работа с websockets в aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

Как мне организовать двунаправленный обмен данными через websocket соединение в aiohttp? Например, есть такой обработчик:

```
import asyncio

q = asyncio.Queue()

@asyncio.coroutine
def websocket_handler(request):
    ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
    ws.start(request)
    while True:
        # input_msg = yield from ws.receive()
        output_msg = yield from q.get()
        ws.send_str(output_msg)
    return ws
```

Есть очередь, через которую поступают сообщения для конкретного соединения, и я их отправляю клиенту.

Куда мне воткнуть строку для приёма сообщений от клиента `input_msg = yield from ws.receive()`?
Ведь в данном случае, пока один из операторов `yield from` не завершится, то второй не начнётся, и у меня получится, что я могу либо принимать сообщения, либо отправлять. Как поступить в данном случае?

Answer (score 1):

```
listener_task = asyncio.ensure_future(ws.receive())
producer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(producer())
done, pending = await asyncio.wait([listener_task, producer_task], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
```

Воспользуйтесь вот таким приемом, а ту корутину что вы не дождались отмените task.cancel() вот таким методом.